# CSV keeps overwriting

Tags: python, excel, csv, tkinter, overwrite

I am trying to make a quick bookkeeping program for my parents in Python. How I want it to work is the following. Everytime my parents open this program, i want it to make a new line in the excel-file. The problem is that everytime the program runs, it overwrites itself. Below, you see my code

```
from tkinter import *
import csv
import pandas as pd

root = Tk()
root.title('Boekhouding 2020')
root.minsize(250, 100)
#Weeknummer
Label1 = Label(root, text= "Weeknummer").grid(row=1, column=1)
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=1, column=2)
#Omschrijving
Label2 = Label(root, text= "Omschrijving").grid(row=2, column=1)
e2 = Entry(root)
e2.grid(row=2, column=2)
#Bedrag
Label3 = Label(root, text= "Bedrag").grid(row=3, column=1)
e3 = Entry(root)
e3.grid(row=3, column=2)



##  Exporteren naar Excel
def export(oms,bedrag,weeknummer):
    with open(r"C:\Users\frank\Desktop\Boekhouding.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        row_export()
        thewriter.writerow([oms,bedrag,weeknummer])

## Klik definition
def myclick():
    mylabel = Label(root, text='Hello ' + e1.get())
    mylabel.grid(row=5, column=1)
    export(e2.get(),e3.get(),e1.get())

## Rowcounter
def row_export():
    with open(r"C:\Users\frank\Desktop\Boekhouding.csv",'r')as csv_file:
        fileObject = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in fileObject:
            print(row)
            export(row[0],row[1],row[2])



## All buttons
mybutton = Button(root, text="exporteren naar excel", command=myclick)
mybutton.grid(row=4, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 7.2. Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 3):

From the definition of Python's [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
Character Meaning
   'r'    open for reading (default)
   'w'    open for writing, truncating the file first
   'x'    open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists
   'a'    open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists
   'b'    binary mode
   't'    text mode (default)
   '+'    open for updating (reading and writing)
```

Use the correct mode.  `'w'` always starts with an empty file.  `'a'` is the correct mode for always writing to the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Try 'a' instead 'w' and inform what happens.
'w' is only for writing and cursor do not move to the end of the file, so it overwrites

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open